# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':

Tags: jquery

I m trying to close my jquery ui model popup from an iframe but i keep getting this error:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://cs44.salesforce.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://c.cs44.visual.force.com').

What could be the problem, i have tried changing the domains, used almost all the combinations, still can't resolve this problem.

Any help is appreciated, Thank You.

Page Code:

```
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();


    j$(document).ready(function() {
        j$('input[id$=btnCloseModalDialog]').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            closeModalDialog();
        });
    });

   function closeModalDialog() {
        var cross_result = new Object();
        cross_result.action = 'close_modal_dialog_refresh';

        j$.postMessage(
          'hello world',
          'https://cs44.salesforce.com',
          parent
        );
    }
```

Comment: Are you using add blocker?:D I have had few problems because of adblock.

Comment: No there is no adblocker

Comment: That's where code snippets are required along with the markups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My case the problem was that my developer mode was on, once i turned off my developer mode, problem was solved.

Hope it helps :)